# iPad SELECT element not obviously scrollable

Tags: ios, ipad, mobile-safari, user-experience

(This is for a browser-based App, and I'm testing on the iPad.)

I'm using a SELECT element to give the user a selection of things they can do. Someone on the team just reported that some options were missing. Investigation turned up the fact that since the little scroller disappears shortly after the SELECT drop down list appears, he didn't realize there were more options below the fold.

This seems like a real usability problem to me. Unless you know that there should be more options, or you happen to be tuned in to the very subtle comes-n-goes scrollbar in the drop down list, you aren't going to know to scroll down to see more options.

On the iPhone this isn't a problem, because the select has that spinny thing that makes it clear that there are more options.

So I'm left with this usability puzzle. I like using a SELECT, because it provides the best experience on various platforms automatically. But I don't like Apple's design decision to hide the fact that there are more options when they don't all fit in the drop down box.

Any suggestions? Ideas?

Comment: They're not hiding that fact. As you stated, they flash the scroll indicators to show that there *is* more content. It's the same in a native app.

Comment: The flash is very quick, and I suspect (though have no evidence of this) that many/most users aren't even aware of that hint. In most cases, the fact that you need to scroll is obvious. You are looking at a list of states, and it stops at Indiana. You are looking at your list of songs and they all start with the letter A.

In my case, the user is discovering features and they are being presented in an order that only made sense to some marketing guy. It is emphatically NOT obvious that there would be more options than the 10 on the screen.

Comment: FYI: I've registered a bug report with Apple: Bug # 11155060

Answer (score 0):

I think you're worrying about nothing. The Select element on the iPad presents a classic tableview inside a popover controller. Anyone who doesn't at least attempt to scroll a tableview that clearly fills up all the available space (e.g. no blank rows) is probably not familiar with the platform as a whole. Plus, if they dismiss and re-tap it, they'll get the scroller flash again. It takes very little time to get used to the fact that tables are frequently scrollable, and that scrollable areas flash their scrollbars when they first appear.

Comment: Perhaps, but this was a developer on the team who uses this thing every day. And he's one of the smartest guys you'll ever meet. The fact that HE didn't grok that items were scrolled off the list is what made me nervous. They don't even do something like have the last option only half-way on the screen.

Comment: One person is not representative of the population. Very smart people do incredibly dumb things all the time (and even worse, because they're smart and they know it, they may not even realize that they're doing something dumb).

Comment: I've now heard this complaint from two managers as well. That's 3/3 people who were doing QA. I think Apple blew this UI decision. The scroll bar should remain visible, or at least I should have the option of saying it should.

Comment: @jesmith: Having the scrollbar remain visible violates the fundamental design of scrollable areas in iOS. Tens of millions of people interact with scrollable areas in iOS every single day. The correct thing to do is absolutely to stick with the native platform conventions instead of trying to roll your own.

Comment: I don't disagree with you there. That particular design element is something Apple decided, and I'm not going to break the paradigm. I'm just saying that Apple got it wrong. (Note that I also turned scroll bars back on about 2 minutes after trying to use Lion with them hidden. Apple doesn't seem to recognize that the scrollbar serves two purposes. It is a tool for scrolling [not needed on touch] and it is a clue that there is stuff you cannot see [which is still needed with touch.)